# Android websocket stream video playback

Tags: android, sockets, video, web, playback

How to playback video stream from web socket address like :
`ws://somevideserver.net:8410/5b03a7aad01502281a39`?

I tried using `WebSocketClient` and successfully connect to port, but how to retrieve stream and send it to player?

```
                URI uri;
                try {
                    uri = new URI(stremURL);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
                mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
                    @Override
                    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "[getStreamURL] = "+"Opened");
//                            mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);

                        startStreaming();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(String s) {
                        final String message = s;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.d(TAG, "[getStreamURL] message = "+message);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable websocket) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "[getStreamURL] = "+"Closed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "[getStreamURL] = "+"Error");
                    }
                };
                mWebSocketClient.connect();
```

Comment: Do you have any solution? I try to play video from websocket in android, Please help me! @Aleksey Neronov @ Aleksey Neronov

Comment: Unfortunately I have no solution for the moment.